# Adding an MMIO peripheral to Rocket-chip as a submodule

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I followed the [MMIO Peripherals](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Customization/MMIO-Peripherals.html) page from the Chipyard documentation to learn about adding modules to rocket-chip within Chipyard framework - and all that seems to have worked pretty well. I summed up my experiences and tried to write it in a slower pace on the pages of the [Chisel Learning Journey](https://github.com/Intensivate/learning-journey/wiki/Adding-an-MMIO-Peripheral) <== adding that only if the person answering question may want to take a look and see that I've got everything working correctly. In other words, I added the MMIO with in the `example` package of Chipyard and it compiles, generates simulator, responds properly to toy benchmark I devised, I even see the corresponding waveforms in gtkwave.

Now, the next step I would like to take is to separate this dummy design (it literally just reads from a memory mapped register that holds a hardcoded value) from the chipyard/rocket-chip infrastructure in the sense that it is housed in a separate repo, that will become a submodule of my chipyard. So, to do that, I've started from [this page](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Customization/Custom-Chisel.html) and took all the steps as given there:

1. a new repo was created, called it `my-chip`
2. into the `my-chip` I added `build.sbt` of the following content:

```
    organization := "My Chip"
    version := "1.0"
    name := "my-chip"
    scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
```

3. into the `my-chip` I added `src/main/scala/JustRead.scala` the one built through the mentioned pages of the Learning Journey
4. within the JustRead.scala I only replaced the `package` line so that now it is:

```
    package my-chip
```

5. then, I added the `my-chip` repo as a submodule to path: `chipyard/generators/my-chip`
6. finally I added appropriate lines to `chipyard/generators/chipyard/src/main/scala/DigitalTop.scala` as follows:

```
package chipyard

import chisel3._

import freechips.rocketchip.subsystem._
import freechips.rocketchip.system._
import freechips.rocketchip.config.Parameters
import freechips.rocketchip.devices.tilelink._

// ------------------------------------
// BOOM and/or Rocket Top Level Systems
// ------------------------------------

// DOC include start: DigitalTop
class DigitalTop(implicit p: Parameters) extends System
  with testchipip.CanHaveTraceIO // Enables optionally adding trace IO
  with testchipip.CanHaveBackingScratchpad // Enables optionally adding a backing scratchpad
  with testchipip.CanHavePeripheryBlockDevice // Enables optionally adding the block device
  with testchipip.CanHavePeripherySerial // Enables optionally adding the TSI serial-adapter and port
  with sifive.blocks.devices.uart.HasPeripheryUART // Enables optionally adding the sifive UART
  with sifive.blocks.devices.gpio.HasPeripheryGPIO // Enables optionally adding the sifive GPIOs
  with sifive.blocks.devices.spi.HasPeripherySPIFlash // Enables optionally adding the sifive SPI flash controller
  with icenet.CanHavePeripheryIceNIC // Enables optionally adding the IceNIC for FireSim
  with chipyard.example.CanHavePeripheryInitZero // Enables optionally adding the initzero example widget
  with chipyard.example.CanHavePeripheryGCD // Enables optionally adding the GCD example widget
  with my-chip.CanHavePeripheryJustRead // <=== ADDED THIS LINE
  with chipyard.example.CanHavePeripheryStreamingFIR // Enables optionally adding the DSPTools FIR example widget
  with chipyard.example.CanHavePeripheryStreamingPassthrough // Enables optionally adding the DSPTools streaming-passthrough example widget
  with nvidia.blocks.dla.CanHavePeripheryNVDLA // Enables optionally having an NVDLA
{
  override lazy val module = new DigitalTopModule(this)
}

class DigitalTopModule[+L <: DigitalTop](l: L) extends SystemModule(l)
  with testchipip.CanHaveTraceIOModuleImp
  with testchipip.CanHavePeripheryBlockDeviceModuleImp
  with testchipip.CanHavePeripherySerialModuleImp
  with sifive.blocks.devices.uart.HasPeripheryUARTModuleImp
  with sifive.blocks.devices.gpio.HasPeripheryGPIOModuleImp
  with sifive.blocks.devices.spi.HasPeripherySPIFlashModuleImp
  with icenet.CanHavePeripheryIceNICModuleImp
  with chipyard.example.CanHavePeripheryGCDModuleImp
  with my-chip.CanHavePeripheryJustReadTopModuleImp // <=== AND THIS LINE
  with freechips.rocketchip.util.DontTouch
// DOC include end: DigitalTop
```

7. Then, I created a config in `chipyard/generators/chipyard/src/main/scala/configs/RocketConfig.scala` as follows:

```
class JustReadTLRocketConfig extends Config(
  new chipyard.iobinders.WithUARTAdapter ++
  new chipyard.iobinders.WithTieOffInterrupts ++
  new chipyard.iobinders.WithBlackBoxSimMem ++
  new chipyard.iobinders.WithTiedOffDebug ++
  new chipyard.iobinders.WithSimSerial ++
  new testchipip.WithTSI ++
  new chipyard.config.WithUART ++
  new chipyard.config.WithBootROM ++
  new chipyard.config.WithL2TLBs(1024) ++
  new my-chip.WithJustRead ++          // <=== THIS LINE ADDED
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithNoMMIOPort ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithNoSlavePort ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithInclusiveCache ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithNExtTopInterrupts(0) ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithNBigCores(1) ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.WithCoherentBusTopology ++
  new freechips.rocketchip.system.BaseConfig)
```

8. Finally, I changed the main `build.sbt` the one in chipyard root to hold these lines additionally:

```
lazy val my-chip = (project in file("generators/my-chip"))
  .dependsOn(rocketchip, chisel_testers, midasTargetUtils)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

and

```
lazy val chipyard = conditionalDependsOn(project in file("generators/chipyard"))
  .dependsOn(boom, hwacha, sifive_blocks, sifive_cache, utilities, iocell,
    sha3, // On separate line to allow for cleaner tutorial-setup patches
    my-chip, // <=== ADDED THIS
    dsptools, `rocket-dsptools`,
    gemmini, icenet, tracegen, ariane, nvdla)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

Now, when running `make CONFIG=JustReadTLRocketConfig`, I get the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m
[info] Loading settings for project chipyard-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/apaj/chipyard/project
[error] [/home/apaj/chipyard/build.sbt]:166: Pattern matching in val statements is not supported
```

Looking around didn't really help as I am lacking any scala/software building skills, so couldn't make much of [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2290), for example...

My spider sense tells me I messed up something in the paths within internal organization of the chipyard, so... please, some help from an experienced user would be much appreciated. Thanks.

*EDIT: typos and adding point 8.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the `-` in `lazy val my-chip` and `package my-chip`. If you want to use a `-` in a scala name you can wrap the name in backticks, like `` `my-chip` ``.